# Issues with auto layout on iPhone, align uilabel.center x to superview.center x

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, autolayout, size-classes

I'm using auto layout and size classes with Xcode 7 and am running into an issue with one particular scene.  The view has a tableView with a UILabel above it that displays the date.  The UILabel is constrained 24 points from the superview's top and centered horizontally on the superview.  The user can access a couple of menu views which are presented modally.  So far so good.

However, when the modal view is dismissed, the label disappears.  I logged its frame, as well as the bounds of the superview, in viewDidAppear: and found that the superview's width was being listed as 1024, putting the label's center at 512, which is offscreen on iPhone.  I don't have any code that's manipulating the frame or the constraints, and the tableview (which is constrained to the superviews leading, bottom, and trailing edges and 8 points from the bottom of the UILabel) is appearing normally.

I'm using size classes with auto layout, but I'm not sure what could be causing this issue.

Here's the log in viewDidAppear before opening and dismissing a modal view:

self.view.width is 320.000000; self.dayLabel.center is 160.250000; self.dayLabel.isHidden is 0; self.dayLabel.text is 07/18/2016

Here's the log after opening and dismissing a modal view:

self.view.width is 1024.000000; self.dayLabel.center is 512.000000; self.dayLabel.isHidden is 0; self.dayLabel.text is  07/18/2016

This is happening when using the simulator or a device.  Any suggestions or clues as to what could be going on would be incredibly helpful.

Comment: So you have no code changing any frames or constraints in viewWillAppear and viewDidAppear? You only have two constraints on the UILabel, are there any other constraints on it?

Comment: @JingJingTao, correct, no frame changing code in viewWillAppear or viewDidAppear, and there's a vertical spacing constraint set from the tableView top to the label bottom, but this shouldn't cause an issue since it's a vertical constraint.  To be safe, I tested it out by adding another UILabel just above the dayLabel, only setting the new label's top spacing to the superview top and centered it horizontally.  The new UILabel ended up getting pushed offscreen with my dayLabel.

Comment: Could you post a picture of the storyboard so I can see all the constraints?